# How to use function in other class c#

Tags: c#

i have app with gui[image]

I put function checkproxy() in Form1.cs it works correctly and i want move function checkproxy() to other class but if i put checkproxy() in other class it will error with Invoke and richTextBox3

```
namespace test3
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public bool continueThreads = false;
    string[] proxyList = null;
    List<Thread> threadList = new List<Thread>();
    int proxynum = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            int n = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
            Thread[] tl = new Thread[n + 1];
            threadList = tl.ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
            {
                threadList[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(checkproxy));
            }
            for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
            {
                threadList[i].Start();
            }
            continueThreads = true;
            proxyList = richTextBox1.Lines;
    }
    public void checkproxy()
    {
        while (continueThreads)
        {

            if (proxynum >= proxyList.Length)
            {
                continueThreads = false;
            }
            if (proxynum < proxyList.Length)
            {
                string proxy = proxyList[proxynum];
                proxynum += 1;
                string info = "";
                try
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    info += "Live || " + proxy + Environment.NewLine;
                    this.Invoke(new Action(() => richTextBox3.Text += info));
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

this is screenshot error
[image]

Comment: `it will error with Invoke and richTextBox3` Then refactor your code,  move that code to some other function and make `checkproxy` to return some value.

Comment: could you please post a screenshot of the error I did not understand what is going wrong.

Comment: What is the relationship of the new location to the old one? It sounds like some visibility problems.

Comment: @Uri Popov: i added screenshot

Answer (score 3):

Your method `checkproxy` uses `Form1` class members (`continueThreads`, `proxynum` and others) directly.

If you really want do move it outside of this class (I'm not sure it is good idea since this method looks very closely related to your class) - you need to refactor this method and pass all class members it uses as method input parameters like

```
public void checkproxy(bool continueThreads.....)
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `this` is a `System.Windows.Forms.Form` in original context. 
To be able to `Invoke` interface update from another thread/async task, you need to use it (as you did correctly in your original code).

But once you move the function into separate class, there is no more notion of a `Conntrol` or `Form` there, so `this` is a class itself, which does not have `Invoke` implementation.

One possible solution: you need to refactor your method in a way, that he is able to call `Form`'s function, that internally calls `Invoke`.